# Extend Application in Android Why does not work?

Tags: extend, android

I have a class which is extending Application

```
public class MyContext extends Application {

    private String _eposta;
    public String getEposta() 
    {
        return _eposta;
    }
    public void setEposta(String eposta) {
        _eposta = eposta;
    }

    private String _sifre;
    public String getSifre() 
    {
        return _sifre;
    }
    public void setSifre(String sifre) {
        _sifre = sifre;
    }
```

And I have a main Activity class

```
 eposta = epostaTxt.getText().toString();
    sifre = parolaTxt.getText().toString();
    ((MyContext)getApplication()).setEposta(eposta);
    ((MyContext)getApplication()).setEposta(sifre);
```

**But on this line: ((MyContext)getApplication()).setEposta(eposta) application fall into the catch field.**

By the way I declare the class into the manifest

```
<application android:name="com.mobil.eposta.MyContext"
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                 android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: In your catch block use `e.printStackTrace()` then post the logcat to show the exception you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't do this:

```
((MyContext)getApplication()).setEposta(eposta)
```

do this:

```
MyContext.setEposta(eposta)
```

should work =)

Answer (score 0):

If you have correctly set the application within the manifest file, try to do this:

```
eposta = epostaTxt.getText().toString();
sifre = parolaTxt.getText().toString();
MyContext gv = (MyContext)getApplicationContext();
gv.setEposta(eposta);
gv.setSifre(sifre);
```